# Best way to read single byte from array of bytes

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

I have array of bytes and I want to read those bytes one by one and convert it into int. I am getting date in byte of array so need to create DataTime object from that. I am using following code. What should the best approach for the same from performance perspective.

```
byte[] date = {25, 10, 13, 04, 16, 26} //day month year hour minute second

CaptureTime = new DateTime(
                        (int)(new ArraySegment<byte>(date, 2, 1).ToArray()[0]), // Year
                        (int)(new ArraySegment<byte>(date, 1, 1).ToArray()[0]), // Month
                        (int)(new ArraySegment<byte>(date, 0, 1).ToArray()[0]), // Day
                        (int)(new ArraySegment<byte>(date, 3, 1).ToArray()[0]), //Hours
                        (int)(new ArraySegment<byte>(date, 4, 1).ToArray()[0]), //Minutes
                        (int)(new ArraySegment<byte>(date, 5, 1).ToArray()[0])); //Seconds
```

Above code is working fine but performance point of view is that fine or there is more good approach to handle this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: wtf is wrong with `(int)date[2]`

Comment: Code clearly missing couple conversion to/from string :)... Really not clear why would you put such complicated code as starting point.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`byte` is an 8-bit unsigned integer that will implicitly get upcast to an `int` when needed.

Maybe I'm under-thinking things, but what's wrong with the obvious and efficient:

```
byte[] octets = {25, 10, 13, 04, 16, 26} //day month year hour minute second

DateTime date = new DateTime(
                  2000 + octets[2] , // year
                         octets[1] , // month
                         octets[0] , // day
                         octets[3] , // hour
                         octets[4] , // minutes
                         octets[5]   // seconds
                ) ;
Console.WriteLine( "The date is: {0:F}" , date ) ;
```

Which produces the expected:

```
The date is: Friday, October 25, 2013 4:16:26 AM
```

Comment: @GrantWinney. Fixed it. It's the drugs, I tell you!